# How to solve convolution where function is on the left side

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am tasked with finding the convolution

$$g(t)=2t+5\int_{0}^{t}\sin(\tau)g(t-\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau$$

I can see that this is the convolution of $\sin(t)$ and $g(t)$ but I don't know how to solve it because I'm solving for $g$ on both sides. What do I do here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just take $g$ to be constant zero...

Answer (score 1):

For the edited question, the answer would be:
By the properties of Laplace transform you have
$$\mathcal{L}(g)=2\mathcal{L}(t)+5\mathcal{L}(\sin(t)) \mathcal{L}(g).$$

If you calculate the transforms of $t$ and $\sin⁡(t)$ then you can solve for $\mathcal{L}(g)$ and find $g$ as the function which has that Laplace transform.

---

Old answer.
Let $f(t)=\sin(t)$, you have that
$$g=f*g.$$
But the convolution theorem implies that
$$\mathcal{L}(g)=\mathcal{L}(f)\mathcal{L}(g).$$
If $\mathcal{L}(g)\neq0$, then $\mathcal{L}(f)=1$, which we know is not true. Then it has to be $\mathcal{L}(g)=0$, which implies that $g\equiv 0$.

Comment: So in other words g(t)=0?

Comment: Yes. Because of all the blah blah above.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I made an edit to the question. How would this change things?

Comment: Well... it'd change a lot =S

Comment: Now you have $\mathcal{L}(g)=2\mathcal{L}(t)+5\mathcal{L}(\sin(t)) \mathcal{L}(g)$. If you calculate the transforms of $t$ and $\sin(t)$ then you can solve for $\mathcal{L}(g)$. Then go back to $g$ guessing which function would have such a Laplace transform.

Comment: If you don't get it right I suggest you start a new question maybe since it is not the same problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the integration variable gives the equivalent integral equation
$$
g(t)=2t+5\int_0^t\sin(t-τ)g(τ)dτ
$$
You read of $g(0)=0$ and
$$
g'(t)=2+5\int_0^t\cos(t-τ)g(τ)dτ
$$
and after that $g'(0)=2$ and
$$
g''(t)=5g(t)-5\int_0^t\sin(t-τ)g(τ)dτ=4g(t)+2t
$$
This last differential equation has the solution
$$
g(t)=\frac54\sinh(2t)-\frac12t.
$$